# Adding obstacles & collision to canvas game

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html-canvas

I  am trying to add some obstacles to the canvas game that I've got but something seems to be wrong and I can't seem to put my finger on it.

I just want some simple walls here and there to make the game harder and collision with the walls (so that if the player hits the wall it's game over).

I have an array that I have created

```
 obstacle =  [[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0]],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0]],
```

The function for the obstacle

```
function obstacle() {
  empty.push({obstacle});

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(obstacle);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#7a26ce";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

And where I would essentially call it. The initiate function.

```
function init() { // Reset and intiate game objects
  score = 0; // set start score to 0
  grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);


  var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
  snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y); // Start direction
  grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);
  setFood();
  grid._grid = grid._grid.concat(obstacle);
}
```

Grid object

```
grid = {
    width: null,  // Amount of columns 
    height: null, // Amount of rows
    _grid: null,  // Array
    init: function(d, c, r) { // initiation with direction, columns and rows.
        this.width = c; // Set width to number of columns (c)
        this.height = r;  // set height to number of rows (r)
        this._grid = []; // Initiate grid with empty array
        for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]); 
            for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d); // set current column and push new value for each row in column
            }
        }
    },
    set: function(val, x, y) { // set values for the grid cells with x and y position 
        this._grid[x][y] = val;
    },

    get: function(x, y) { // get the value of x and y position
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }

}
```

Snake object

```
snake = { // Creating snake
    direction: null, // Direction of snake
    last: null,      // last element in queue pointer
    _queue: null,    // queue array

    // Sets start position of snake, same initiation method as before
    init: function(d, x, y) {
        this.direction = d; // Direction set to d
        this._queue = []; // Another empty queue array
        this.insert(x, y); // Inserting x & y position
    },

    // Insert method that adds elements to queue with x and y position
    insert: function(x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y}); // unshift prepends an element to array
        this.last = this._queue[0];
    },

    // Remove function to remove and return element to queue 
    remove: function() {
        return this._queue.pop(); // pop returns the last element of array
    }
};
```

Here's a [fiddle][1] for the full code.

[1]:

```js
var
// variables
COLS = 25, // Columns
ROWS = 25, // Rows
EMPTY = 0, // Empty Cell
SNAKE = 1, // Snake
FRUIT = 2, // Fruit
LEFT  = 0, // left direction (key)
UP    = 1, // up direction (key)
RIGHT = 2, // right direction (key)
DOWN  = 3, // down direction (key)
KEY_LEFT  = 37, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
KEY_UP    = 38, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
KEY_RIGHT = 39, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
KEY_DOWN  = 40, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
obstacle = [[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0]],
           

// Objects 
canvas,   // Canvas
ctx,   // Canvas render
keystate, // Key inputs
frames,   // frames per second
score;   // player score

grid = {
 width: null,  // Amount of columns 
 height: null, // Amount of rows
 _grid: null,  // Array
 init: function(d, c, r) { // initiation with direction, columns and rows.
  this.width = c; // Set width to number of columns (c)
  this.height = r;  // set height to number of rows (r)
        this._grid = []; // Initiate grid with empty array
  for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
   this._grid.push([]); // push obstacle into empty grid
   for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
    this._grid[x].push(d); // set current column and push new value for each row in column
   }
  }
 },
 set: function(val, x, y) { // set values for the grid cells with x and y position 
  this._grid[x][y] = val;
 },
 
 get: function(x, y) { // get the value of x and y position
  return this._grid[x][y];
 }
    
}

snake = { // Creating snake
 direction: null, // Direction of snake
 last: null,   // last element in queue pointer
 _queue: null,  // queue array

    // Sets start position of snake, same initiation method as before
 init: function(d, x, y) {
  this.direction = d; // Direction set to d
  this._queue = []; // Another empty queue array
  this.insert(x, y); // Inserting x & y position
 },
    
    // Insert method that adds elements to queue with x and y position
 insert: function(x, y) {
  this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y}); // unshift prepends an element to array
  this.last = this._queue[0];
 },
 
    // Remove function to remove and return element to queue 
 remove: function() {
  return this._queue.pop(); // pop returns the last element of array
 }
};

function obstacle() {
    empty.push({obstacle});
            
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(obstacle);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#7a26ce";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
    
function setFood() { // Food for hungry snake 
 var empty = []; // tracks all empty places in the grid
 // for loop to find all empty cells in grid
 for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
  for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
   if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
    empty.push({x:x, y:y});
   }
  }
 }
 // variable randomposition to pick random empty cell
 var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random()*(empty.length - 1))];
 grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

function main() { // call all the functions that we will use in the game
 // canvas 
 canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = COLS*20;  // Sets canvas width to columns * 20 
 canvas.height = ROWS*20; // Sets canvas height to columns * 20 
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 document.body.appendChild(canvas); // Adds canvas element to the body of the document
 ctx.font = "12px sans-serif"; // font 
 frames = 0;
 keystate = {};
 
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) { // Track all keyboard input
  keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
 });
 document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) { // Track all keyboard input
  delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
 });
 
 init(); // Initiate Game Loop 
 loop(); // Start Game Loop 
}

function init() { // Reset and intiate game objects
 score = 0; // set start score to 0
 grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);
    
    
 var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
 snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y); // Start direction
 grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);
 setFood();
    grid._grid = grid._grid.concat(obstacle);
}

function loop() { // Game loop for rendering and objects
    update();
 draw();
 window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas); // Canvas will call loop function when it needs to redraw
}

function update() { // update function
 frames++;
 // Keyboard input
 if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
  snake.direction = LEFT;
 }
 if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
  snake.direction = UP;
 }
 if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
  snake.direction = RIGHT;
 }
 if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
  snake.direction = DOWN;
 }
 // Update game every 5 frames.
 if (frames%5 === 0) {
  // last element from the snake queue 
  var nx = snake.last.x;
  var ny = snake.last.y;
  // Updating the position of snake depending on the direction it is heading
  switch (snake.direction) {
   case LEFT:
    nx--;
    break;
   case UP:
    ny--;
    break;
   case RIGHT:
    nx++;
    break;
   case DOWN:
    ny++;
    break;
  }
  // if statement checking conditions whether game should keep running or reset aka game over
  if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
   0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
   grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
  ) {
   return init();
            
  }
  // Checks the new position of the snake and if it's on a fruit item or not.
  if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
   // If it is on a fruit item it will increase your score and create a new food in a random cell.
   score++;
   setFood();
            
  } else {
   // Takes out the tail (first item) from queue and removes identifier from the grid.
   var tail = snake.remove();
   grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
            
  }
        
  // Snake identifier that is created at the new position and is added to the queue 
  grid.set(SNAKE, nx, ny);
  snake.insert(nx, ny);
        
 }
}

function draw() { // render grid to canvas
 var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;  // Calculate tile width
 var th = canvas.height/grid.height; // Calculate tile height
 
 for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) { // for-loop loops through entire grid to draw cells
  for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
   // Depending on the identifier of each cell sets certain fillstyle defined below. 
   switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
    case EMPTY:
     ctx.fillStyle = "#5a5a5a";
     break;
    case SNAKE:
     ctx.fillStyle = "#B54548";
     break;
    case FRUIT:
     ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
     break;
                case obstacle:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                    break;
   }
   ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
  }
 }
 // Change fillstyle and show score on the screen.
 ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
 ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 10, canvas.height-10);
}
// Game Start!
main();
```

**The Problem** 
My obstacles doesn't seem to be showing up on the grid at all, I'm not entirely sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GDSE. To be of help, we would need more information about what type of game you are making (presumably a Snake-like game), what game engine or library you are using, be more precise about your problem, etc. There are a lot of function and variables for which we know nothing (for example, snake.init(...) and the grid object)

Comment: What is your problem? Do you suppose we'll write this piece of code instead of you or what?

Comment: Thank you, and yes it is a snake game. I wanted to post the entire code however I was recommended to just post the code that relates to the problem from SO. In the fiddle is all the code that I am actually using.

Comment: My problem is that my obstacles aren't showing up, I just asked for guidance that is all.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what are you trying to achieve? You want to create obstacle from array of point coordinates, right?

Comment: You can put your fiddle in a Stack Snippet in your question instead, especially as the code in your fiddle has at least one error (you are using an array as a case in a switch).

Comment: Precisely! I want to create obstacles that the snake has to avoid in order not to lose the game. And I figured the best way to do this would be using an array with coordinates. However it fails to show up on the grid no matter how I push it.

Comment: I edited the post with the fiddle snippet hopefully it should work. Apologise for the rookie mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render loop, you have a switch case that tests a cell to find out it's type, wheter is a snake, fruit or obstacle. The problem, in your case, is that you are testing an integer against a 2D array of integers (which will never match). This is caused by the fact that you use 2 different variables for the main grid and for the obstacles.

To fix the problem, you should write the walls in the grid variable with all your other cell types and in your render switch case, test for it's value (you could put 3 for a wall and define its constant at the beggining of your file).

Here is a link to your JSFidle with minor updates to show your walls (I have only placed one at the (0, 0) position in the init() function, but you can place them where you'd like) : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg26rt42/3/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have solved it now and added working collision. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @xioner No problems. If i have answered your question, feel free to mark this answer as the accepted one, by clicking the checkmark in the top left.